# Hooks : BeforeTestRun and AfterTestRun are NOT running when running specflow tests

Tags: c#, automation, nunit, bdd, specflow

1. Created a Feature File
2. Added a Scenario with Given, When, Then
3. Created a Hook File and added all hooks like [BeforeTestRun], [BeforeScenario], [BeforeStep] etc..
4. Inside each hook method I have added a console writeline statement to see if all attributes are running
5. When I am running tests, I see that Except [BeforeTestRun] all other attributes are running fine and writeline is printed

Hooks.cs

```
[Binding]
public class GlobalHooks
{
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static async Task BeforeTestRun()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Before Test Run"));
    }

    [AfterTestRun]
    public static async Task AfterTestRun()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("After Test Run"));
    }
}
```

Tried below ways which isn't helping:

1. I have added [Binding] to the Hooks.cs class file
2. I have placed [BeforeTestRun] in the first place inside Hooks class block

Comment: I haven't tried using these hooks as `async` methods. Maybe try `public static void X()` - non async methods?

Comment: SpecFlow captures the standard output differently. I wonder if you can pass an `ISpecFlowOutputHelper` as a parameter to the BeforeTestRun method, and then use that instead of `Console.WriteLine(string)`?